# Using waveletstudio library

Tags: c#, wavelet, dwt

Please i hope that someone here already used waveletStudio library.
I have a problem : when i pass an Array with more than 9.000.000 of samples, program exit with `An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in WaveletStudio.dll`.
Please help me, library doesn't have documentation.

```
Signal sign = new Signal(double[] samples);
var wavelet = MotherWavelet.LoadFromName("sym6");
var output = DWT.ExecuteDWT(sign, wavelet,1);
```

Thankx

Comment: Can't you split the array and pass it as chunks?

Comment: It's another idea, i try it. Thks